# Locking settings

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Got a 7 year old on Minecraft PE and want to know if there is a way to lock settings. I think I have multiplayer off but I am not even sure which side of the button signifies off. I know it's sounds dumb. Sorry. Just trying to keep him safe and not accessible for chatting etc

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per cutypi's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/157310/can-i-disable-multiplayer-in-minecraft-pocket-edition), the simplest way would simply be to turn off wifi and data for the device that he is playing on.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that iCloud backup is "on". If the world is lost or deleted, wipe the device and restore from back-up.
Or, make a copy of the world using iExplorer or similar free software. These tools will let you copy, or place MineCraft worlds into the MineCraft Worlds folder. Make sure to copy the .dat file and the folder named "db"